# Robustification in lavaan: Difference between M, MV and MVS?

Tags: outliers, robust, confirmatory-factor, lavaan, robust-standard-error

In lavaan, I am running a two-factor CFA on a questionnaire with 28 items, all of which are scored on a 6-point Likert scale. In total I have ~350 participants who completed the questionnaire.

Because of the ordinal nature of the data, I am using ULS instead of ML, and the ordered = T command.

Because I have found outliers in my dataset (both in terms of Mahalonobis distance and generalized Cook's distance, but not in terms of standardized residuals), I want to use a robustification method to reduce the influence of these extreme cases, instead of discarding these observations, as recommended by [Flora et al.](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2012.00055)

Now, based on my understanding, I can do that by choosing the estimator `ULSM`, `ULSMV`, or `ULSMVS`. According to the [lavaan documentation](https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/est.html), the difference is the following:

- `ULSM` estimator uses "robust standard errors and a Satorra-Bentler scaled test statistic";
- `ULSMV` estimator uses " robust standard errors and a mean- and variance adjusted test statistic (using a scale-shifted approach)";
- `ULSMVS` estimator uses "robust standard errors and a mean- and variance adjusted test statistic (aka the Satterthwaite approach)"

Which estimator I use has a very strong effect on my CFI and RMSEA scores (but not SRMR or WRMR), as can be seen in this figure: [image]

However, I cannot find out which of these estimators, the `ULSM`, the `ULSMV`, or the `ULSMVS`, I should use. So,

1. Am I approaching this analysis generally correct, and
2. Which of these estimators should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: my data are not normally distributed.

Answer (score 2):

> Because I have found outliers in my dataset (both in terms of Mahalonobis distance and generalized Cook's distance

These were calculated by treating your 6-point Likert scale as a continuum, right?  So 1 means 1, 2 means 2, ...

> Because of the ordinal nature of the data, I am using ULS instead of ML, and the ordered = T command

The `ordered = TRUE` argument tells `lavaan()` you don't want to treat the Likert scale as a continuum, but as 6 ordinal categories.

> I want to use a robustification method to reduce the influence of these extreme cases ... by choosing the estimator `ULSM`, `ULSMV`, or `ULSMVS`

You don't get anything robust to outliers or nonnormality.  The [`regsem` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=regsem) provides robust ML to reduce the influence of outliers.  If you treated your data as coming from a continuum (do not set `ordered=TRUE`), then you those `lavaan(estimator=)` options provide test statistics robust to nonnormality.  When you invoke the latent-response assumption with `ordered=TRUE`, there is no way to adjust for the degree to which those latent responses are not normally distributed; you simply have to assume normality underlies those discrete responses.

Robitzsch, A. (2020). Why ordinal variables can (almost) always be treated as continuous variables: Clarifying assumptions of robust continuous and ordinal factor analysis estimation methods. *Frontiers in Education, 5*(589965). https://doi.org/10.3389/feduc.2020.589965

> Which of these estimators should I use?

The *`MV` adjustment is generally the most robust, especially when treating data as ordinal.  But your sample is so small for such a large model, I expect even your robust test statistic would not have nominal Type I error rates.

> but not SRMR

That's because RMR, SRMR, and CRMR are based on residuals, not on $\chi^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer!

"These were calculated by treating your 6-point Likert scale as a continuum, right?"

I think so, yes. I used the `faoutlier` package, and the `obs.resid()`, `robustMD()`, and `gCD()` functions with their default settings. 

"The regsem package provides robust ML to reduce the influence of outliers."

Awesome! But when I look in the documentation of the package, I can't figure out how to call the robust ML... Also, is it possible to combine the robust ML with the MV adjustment, to also protect against nonnormality?

Comment: Ah, based on your comment [here](https://groups.google.com/g/lavaan/c/RVQabY9LER8/m/RSUXUY4QAQAJ) I am guessing that the regsem package automatically reduces the influence of outliers, and that it is indeed possible to use the MLR or MLMV estimator.

Thanks!